# Twitter ads API using Java

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Is there a Java client library for Twitter Ads Api? It seems Twitter4J Ads API isn't being maintained.

https://github.com/sprinklr-inc/twitter4j-ads

The latest version of the API is 6.0, while that SDK is for v3.

Thanks!

Comment: most recent commit shows as 8 months ago...for what that's worth.

Comment: Decided to fork and update what I need to v8